# How to add resources to androidTest for android library in AndroidStudio

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio, gradle, android-resources

I made an `androidLibrary` project which contains some `Volley` request classes,
and want to write a unit test for some of these requests.

I have done that like a hundred times, and it works *somehow* after several tries, but never on the first try.

If I try this via androidStudio

RightClick Project->New->Android Resource Directory

you can choose between sourceSets "main", "debug" and "release". There is no `androidTest` option.

If I try it manualy, adding the following folders `[moduleName]/src/androidTest/res/raw`
and put a file inside (lets say image.jpg), I do not get the reference via `R.raw.image`. In fact I haven't access to `R.raw` in my Test at all.

I also tried a Build->rebuild project or Build->clean without success.

In other projects I have a `my.app.namespace.R` along a `my.app.namespace.test.R` which holds all test resources.

So my question is: 
What do I need to do in order to add a `res` folder to my androidTest, which is accessible via `R.[folder].[resId]`?

Am I missing a crucial step after adding the files (i.e. telling gradle explicitly about it)?

Because adding a tag like this in my `build.gradle` also doesn't seem to make any difference:

```
android {
    sourceSets {
        androidTest {
            java.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/androidTest/res']
        }
    }
}
```

If it matters I am using:

- Android Studio 3.1.2
- gradle-wrapper 4.4
- minSdkVersion 19
- targetSdkVersion 27

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out what is going on with the help of [the update of Michael Krussel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28993767/android-studio-gradle-and-androidtest-res-raw) Answer:

Android Studio is **not** compiling the `my.app.namespace.test` package automatically. All you need to do is run the Test the first time, ignoring the errors `AndroidStudio` might present.

After the first run you got access to the whole `test` namespace (including the `*.test.R` class)

No additional gradle config (like `sourceSets` from above) are necessary!

Comment: How you access the resources though? I get `Resources$NotFoundException` for androidTest strings.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to invalidate caches before trying to rebuild/run instrumented tests if you encounter the similar error - at least this did help me on Android Studio 2022.1.1 Patch 2.

To do that, navigate to `Files -> Invalidate Caches...`